# Keystrokes Windows Remote Desktop Connection?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 2008 VPS and connect to it using Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc.exe). I run on it an app that does some tasks simulating keystrokes. It runs perfectly when i'm logged on the VPS and most of the time, i'm logged on it.

But when my workday ends i turn off my computer and disconnect the RDC and this is when the problem starts : if i'm not logged, the app that simulate keystrokes won't work properly. The VPS is still running and the session is still active, but everything that simulates keystrokes does not work.

Is there a way to change this behaviour ? I want the machine to run all the time exactly how it runs when i'm connect to RDC.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with most programs that "interact with the session". When a RDP session is disconnected from the session "shuts down" and anything that would interact with the UI no longer works. If you minimized your RDP session you would likely see it there too.

The only way around this I know of is not to use RDP and see if you can get something like Teamviewer Host, or some other similar software that lets you take over the "console session", that way the console can stay logged in even after you disconnect.

Comment: Thank you for the info ; any ideas of free applications that could achieve this task ?

Comment: [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) is free for non commercial use, that is what I use

Comment: I download it and runned it on the machine. But even with it running, if i log out from RDC, the error persists. Should i do anything else ?

Comment: Once you install the service restart it once from the service manager.

Comment: It's installed, i restarted the service from services.msc, but still when i disconnect from RDC, the app keystrokes don't work :(

Comment: You shouldn't be using RDC to connect anymore, you should be using TeamViewer to connect.

Comment: I understood. I tried it but i get the following error : "“The screen cannot be captured at the moment. This is probably due to fast user switching or a disconnected/minimized Remote Desktop session.”. I'm searching for it.

Comment: If it is still doing that after restarting the service that means your VPS provider has disabled the console session. Either you need better software that does the same goal without faking keypresses or you need to pay for a more expensive server that is not a VPS and is a actual full stand alone server.